# Having problems running my .net project after changing framework to 4.5 from 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I opened up a project and changed it's framework to 4.0 from 4.5 (due to some stupid Firm's restrictions).

```
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built


"MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "My.DataAccessLayer.DimensionDB",
 "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted 


processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align 

the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on 


references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
```

This is a warning. When I run anyhow, it gives me following errors:-

```
The type or namespace name 'Membership' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Membership' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

etc.

I'll highly appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Comment: You sure those are problems and not just warnings? You should be able to run still.

Comment: You're right. This is a warning. when I run, errors appear which I just pasted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your application is targeting `AnyCPU`, but it references `x86` assemblies.

You should change your target to `x86` to resolve these warnings (and allow it to run successfully).

Note that, in 4.5, this would still run since the default includes the (new in 4.5) "Prefer 32-bit" option, which causes `AnyCPU` to use x86 still.